# Window 10: How to run script on Genymotion emulator with appium using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, appium, genymotion

Please help to solve my problem

1. Genymotion with VirtualBox download  from genymotion site and install properly
2. Add Genymotion pluging on eclipse and set Genymotion directory
3. Add virtual device Nexus9 os version 5.1.0  API 22
4. Add Selenium and Appium java client jar files under project
5. Use Genymotion Android Tool and Custom Android SDK tool as Genymotion ADB tool connection setting
6. Configure Appium Setting and run appium
7. Run below source code

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
   import java.net.URL;
   import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

   public class Firstappium {

       static String deviceName = "Nexus9-6.0.0-API23";
       static  WebDriver driver;;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecuteException, IOException {

           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();        
           DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
           DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
                   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus9-5.1.0API22");   
           capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
           capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
           capabilities.setCapability("app","G:/appium/apk/cz.hipercalc.apk");

           driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4720/wd/hub"),capabilities);
           System.out.println("SetUp is successful and Appium Driver is launched successfully");        
       }
   }
   ```
8. Show below log in Appium

> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] Retrying restartAdb
>   error: Error running wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    devices
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    wait-for-device
>   error: Error running wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] Retrying restartAdb
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>   error: Error running wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    devices
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    wait-for-device
>   error: Error running wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    wait-for-device"
>   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
>   could not read ok from ADB Server
>   * could not start server *
>
> info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
>    wait-for-device"
>   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
>   could not read ok from ADB Server
>   * could not start server *
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...\r wait-for-device\"\nerror: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)\r\ncould not read ok from ADB Server\r\n* could not start server *\r\n)","killed":false,"code":4294967295,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...\r wait-for-device\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"G:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...\r wait-for-device\"\nerror: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)\r\ncould not read ok from ADB Server\r\n* could not start server *\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 30628.747 ms - 1226

Answer (score 1):

From the logs what I can is "adb server version does not match".

Try updating your Android SDK first through **ANDROID SDK MANAGER**.

And you need to start appium server before you try to initialise the driver.

When you start appium server, by default it starts with port number 4723.

If you are not mentioning any port number while starting appium server then the url should be `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub`